# Can I pull ODK data into SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, odk

Our back-end is SQL server, and we try to pull all ODK records into our database, so is there a way to do this even through coding, I have no idea even how to start with this thing as I am not expert with ODk things.

Answer (score 1):

You could import the submission.xml using XML-import. You'll probably need to do some transformation depending on how your survey data is organised.

I got some help here when facing the same problem importing XML directly into a MS Access databse. See this link: [Importing ODK XML file to MS Access using XLST transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529947/importing-odk-xml-file-to-ms-access-using-xlst-transformation)